# Trying to get property of non-object in CodeIgniter while updating

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to make update form, that is going to retrieve the data for the specific ID selected, and fill in the form, so its going to be available for updating.
 after pressing on button I am getting the error of **"undefined variable result"** and **"Trying to get property of non-object"**

following is my code.

Mainview

```
   <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/validation_control/addnew" method="post">

        <table align="center" border=2>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Birt Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>            
            <?php
                foreach ($query as $row) 
                {
                    $style='';
                    if($row->status=='deactive'){$style = 'style="text-decoration: line-through"';}
                ?>  

                     <tr <?php echo $style;?>>
                        <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->username; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->fname; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->lname; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo "<img src='../codeigniter/uploads/".$row->userfile."' width=30 height=30>";?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->bdate; ?></td>                        
                        <td>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/validation_control/update_status');?>/<?php echo $row->id;?>/<?php echo $row->status; ?>" ">
                        <?php echo $row->status;?></a>
                        </td>

                         <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/validation_control/edit');?>/<?php echo $row->id;?>">Edit</a></td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                } 
            ?>
                    <tr><td align="center" colspan="8"><input type="submit" value="Add New" /> </td></tr>
                    </table>    

   </form>
```

Edit View

```
<html><body>
 <?php //echo form_open_multipart("validation_control/edit_member/");?>

       <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/validation_control/edit_member/"  method="post" id="email_form" onsumbit="return myFunction()">
            <table align="center" border="2">


                <tr><td>Username :-</td> <td><input type="text" name='uname' value="<?php echo $result[0]->username;?>"/><?php echo form_error('uname'); ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>First Name :- <td><input type="text" name='fname' value="<?php echo $result[0]->fname;?>" /><?php echo form_error('fname'); ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Last Name :- <td><input type="text" name='lname' value="<?php echo $result[0]->lname;?>"/><?php echo form_error('lname'); ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Phone Number :- <td><input type="text" name='phone' value="<?php echo $result[0]->phone;?>"/><?php echo form_error('phone'); ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Email :- <td><input type="text" name='email' value="<?php echo $result[0]->email;?>"?><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Password :-<td><input type="password" name='pass' id='pass' value="<?php echo $result[0]->password;?>"/><?php echo form_error('pass'); ?></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Confirm Password :-<td><input type="password" name='cnfpass' id='cnfpass' value="<?php echo set_value('cnfpass'); ?>"/><?php echo form_error('cnfpass'); ?></td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Birth Date :-<td><input type="datetime-local" name="date" ></td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Image :- <td><input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="60" accept="image/*" value="<?php echo $result[0]->userfile;?>"></td>

                <tr><td>Status :-<td><input type="radio" name="status" value="active" />Active<input type="radio" name="status" value="deactive" />Deactive<input type="radio" name="status" value="delete" />Delete<?php //echo form_error('status'); ?></td></tr>



                <tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="sbmt" id="sbmt" value="Update" ></td></tr>


            </table>
        </form>
</body></html>
```

Control

```
    function edit($member_id)
     {
        $member = $this->validation_model->get_member($member_id);
        //$this->load->view('validation_edit', $member);
        $this->load->view('validation_edit',array('result'=>$member));
     }
    function edit_member($member_id=NULL)
     {
        //$product = $this->validation_model->get_member($member_id);

//      $this->data['title'] = 'Edit Member';

        //validate form input

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname', 'Username', 'required|is_unique[validation.username]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'Firstname', 'required|min_length[2]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Lastname', 'required|min_length[2]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phonenumber', 'required|max_length[10]|is_natural|valid_base64');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cnfpass', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|matches[pass]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
//  echo "calling"; exit;
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('validation_edit');
            }
            else
            {   
            $image_path = $this->upload->data();
                        $data = array(

                            'username'=>$this->input->post('uname'),                        
                            'fname'=>$this->input->post('fname'),
                            'lname'=>$this->input->post('lname'),
                            'phone'=>$this->input->post('phone'),
                            'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                            'password'=>$this->input->post('pass'),
                            'bdate'=>$this->input->post('date'),
                            'status'=>$this->input->post('status'),
                            'userfile'=>$_FILES['userfile']['name']

                            //'userfile' => $image_path[name]
                            );
                $this->validation_model->update_member($data);
                echo $data;
            }
                //redirect();

//      $this->load->view('validation_edit', $this->data);
    }
```

Model

```
public function update_member($data)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $member_id);
    $this->db->update('validation', $data);
}
```

Comment: when it says `undefined variable` you must know that that variable is not existing. `Trying to get property of non-object` you are accessing the variable as an object when it is not.

Comment: Ok Thanks @tomexsans , Now where should i change in my code??

Comment: the error will print the line where the error is coming from, you could start from there

Comment: @tomexsans i think u hv not seen my code.
from where error is coming that line is imp for  fetching data but while clicking on button that line becomes error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller try to use this:

```
function edit($member_id)
 {
    $data['result'] = $this->validation_model->get_member($member_id);

    $this->load->view('validation_edit',$data);
 }
```